# Memory allocation of functions and variables in C

Tags: c, memory, stack, embedded

Depended of the version of the C compiler and compiler flags it is possible to initialize variables on any place in your functions (As far as I am aware).

I'm used to put it all the variables at the top of the function, but the discussion started about the memory use of the variables if defined in any other place in the function.

Below I have written 2 short examples, and I wondered if anyone could explain me (or verify) how the memory gets allocated.

Example 1: Variable y is defined after a possible return statement, there is a possibility this variable won't be used for that reason, as far as I'm aware this doesn't matter and the code (memory allocation) would be the same if the variable was placed at the top of the function. Is this correct?

Example 2: Variable x is initialized in a loop, meaning that the scope of this variable is only within this loop, but what about the memory use of this variable? Would it be any different if placed on the top of the functions? Or just initialized on the stack at the function call?

Edit: To conclude a main question:
Does reducing the scope of the variable or change the location of the first use (so anywhere else instead of top) have any effects on the memory use?

Code example 1

```
static void Function(void){
 uint8_t x = 0;

 //code changing x
 if(x == 2)
 {
  return;
 }

 uint8_t y  = 0;    
 //more code changing y
}
```

Code example 2

```
static void LoopFunction(void){
 uint8_t i = 0;

 for(i =0; i < 100; i ++)
 {
  uint8_t x = i;
  // do some calculations
  uartTxLine("%d", x); 
 }

 //more code
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm used to put it all the variables at the top of the function

This used to be required in the older versions of C, but modern compilers dropped that requirement. As long as they know the type of the variable at the point of its first use, the compilers have all the information they need.

> I wondered if anyone could explain me how the memory gets allocated.

The compiler decides how to allocate memory in the automatic storage area. Implementations are not limited to the approach that gives each variable you declare a separate location. They are allowed to reuse locations of variables that go out of scope, and also of variables no longer used after a certain point.

In your first example, variable `y` is allowed to use the space formerly occupied by variable `x`, because the first point of use of `y` is after the last point of use of `x`.

In your second example the space used for `x` inside the loop can be reused for other variables that you may declare in the `// more code` area.

Comment: Alright, so this means it is actually more efficient to code it this way instead of putting all variables at top where it might not be clear when it is out of scope or when it is going to be used? Or does this still not matter?

Comment: @koldewb It does not matter to the compiler, because it can figure out the area of active use of your variable, and allocate memory accordingly. However, it matters a great deal to people who read your code, so placing variables closer to places where they are used is better than declaring everything at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the story goes like this. When calling a function in raw assembler, it is custom to store everything used by the function on the stack upon entering the function, and clean it up upon leaving. Certain CPUs and ABIs may have a calling convention which involves automatic stacking of parameters.

Likely because of this, C and many other old languages had the requirement that all variables must be declared at the top of the function (or on top of the scope), so that the `{ }` reflect push/pop on the stack.

Somewhere around the 80s/90s, compilers started to optimize such code efficiently, as in they would only allocate room for a local variable at the point where it was first used, and de-allocate it when there was no further use for it. Regardless of where that variable was declared - it didn't matter for the optimizing compiler.

Around the same time, C++ lifted the variable declaration restrictions that C had, and allowed variables to be declared anywhere. However, C did not actually fix this before the year 1999 with the updated C99 standard. In modern C you can declare variables everywhere.

So there is absolutely no performance difference between your two examples, unless you are using an incredibly ancient compiler. It is however considered good programming practice to narrow the scope of a variable as much as possible - though it shouldn't be done at the expense of readability.

Although it is only a matter of style, I would personally prefer to write your function like this:

(note that you are using the wrong printf format specifier for uint8_t)

```
#include <inttypes.h>

static void LoopFunction (void)
{
  for(uint8_t i=0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    uint8_t x = i;
    // do some calculations
    uartTxLine("%" PRIu8, x); 
  }

 //more code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old C allowed only to declare (and initialize) variables at the top of a block.  You where allowed to init a new block (a pair of `{` and `}` characters) anywhere inside a block, so you had then the possibility of declaring variables next to the code using them:

```
... /* inside a block */
{ int x = 3;
    /* use x */
} /* x is not adressabel past this point */
```

And you where permitted to do this in `switch` statements, `if` statements and `while` and `do` statements (everywhere where you can init a new block)

Now, you are permitted to declare a variable anywhere where a statement is allowed, and the scope of that variable goes from the point of declaration to the end of the inner nested block you have declared it into.

Compilers decide when they allocate storage for local variables so, you can all of them allocated when you create a stack frame (this is the gcc way, as it allocates local variables only once) or when you enter in the block of definition (for example, Microsoft C does this way) Allocating space at runtime is something that requires advancing the stack pointer at runtime, so if  you do this only once per stack frame you are saving cpu cycles (but wasting memory locations).  The important thing here is that you are not allowed to refer to a variable location outside of its scoping definition, so if you try to do, you'll get *undefined behaviour*.  I discovered an old bug for a long time running over internet, because nobody take the time to compile that program using Microsoft-C compiler (which failed in a core dump) instead of the commmon use of compiling it with GCC.  The code was using a local variable defined in an inner scope (the `then` part of an if statement) by reference in some other part of the code (as everything was on `main` function, the stack frame was present all the time) Microsoft-C just reallocated the space on exiting the `if` statement, but GCC waited to do it until `main` finished.  The bug solved by just adding a `static` modifier to the variable declaration (making it global) and no more refactoring was neccesary.

```
int main()
{
    struct bla_bla *pointer_to_x;
    ...
    if (something) {
        struct bla_bla x;
        ...
        pointer_to_x = &x;
    }
    /* x does not exist (but it did in gcc) */
    do_something_to_bla_bla(pointer_to_x); /* wrong, x doesn't exist */
} /* main */
```

when changed to:

```
int main()
{
    struct bla_bla *pointer_to_x;
    ...
    if (something) {
        static struct bla_bla x;  /* now global ---even if scoped */
        ...
        pointer_to_x = &x;
    }
    /* x is not visible, but exists, so pointer_to_x continues to be valid */
    do_something_to_bla_bla(pointer_to_x); /* correct now */
} /* main */
```